# MySQL, PHP: Display MySQL table in HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

sorry, I'm still very novice with server-side (back-end) development, thank you for helping in advance.

Recently, I've been developing a web page which you can choose which table you want to display from the mySQL server, then it will create an editable table in HTML using the mySQL table data.

So far, I'm only able to fetch which table to get from mySQL and display it using in the form of an array, which doesn't really look that great.

I wonder if you can display the array in a form of an editable table without knowing the how many columns, column names as it is different for every different table.

Later on, I have to upload the cell that is updated back to mySQL database and I've no idea how to do that as well.

Sorry for the trouble, this website had been a great help for me and the community is great. Thanks a lot!

Image of what I have so far:

[image]

Code I have so far:

SelectTable:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <b>List of Tables</b>
      <table class="table table-condensed selection_table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>

                <?php
                    if ($tableResult = mysqli_query($conn,"show tables")){
                        while($table = mysqli_fetch_array($tableResult)) {
                            echo("<tr> <td>". "<a class = 'list_tables' href = ?clickedTable=$table[0]>". $table[0] . "</a>" ."</td> </tr>");
                        }

                    }else{
                        die("<b>"."No Table in Database!"."</b>");
                    }
                    if (isset($_GET['clickedTable'])){
                        $selectedTable = $_GET["clickedTable"];
                    }
                ?>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

Fetch array from selected table:

```
<?php  
       if (isset($_GET['clickedTable'])){
        echo("<b> Current Table is: </b> ".$selectedTable. "<br/>");

        $query = "SELECT * FROM $selectedTable";

        if ($result = mysqli_query($conn , $query)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                print_r($row);
            }
        }

    }else{
        echo("Please select a table");
    }

?>
```

Comment: You can get the number of columns, and their names, and dynamically display the table. Use `count($row)` to get the number of columns, and use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array` to get the column names - ie as associative array where the column name is the key in the `$row` array

Comment: ^ and you can use array_keys on the first row of data to get a nice array of them keys.  Or you can use explain on the database to get the column names and types, which might be more useul, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: From what I read from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php it seems like mysqli_fetch_assoc still requires name of column???? Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: Nvm Nvm I got it now :D Thank a lot!!!!!! You guys are the best :P

Comment: I've got another question now, after using the mysqli_fetch_assoc, I got the content of the table, but not the title, how can I do that???